# android studio Error executing Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I imported an existing project, it worked, i deleted it and tried to re-import it and here's the error i get:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-24:34 to override.

**here's my Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo_molfix"
    android:label="Molfix"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="DATABASE"
        android:value="molfix.db"
        />
    <meta-data
        android:name="VERSION"
        android:value="2" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="QUERY_LOG"
        android:value="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
        android:value="molfix.dev.molfix" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity" >
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Bvn.BienvenuActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Bvn.ConnexionActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Bvn.InscriptionActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Menu.MenuPActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Menu.BBEnRoute.Trs.TrsBBActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Menu.BBEnRoute.Trs.TrsMamanActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Menu.BBEnRoute.BBERActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Menu.BBEnRoute.Calendar.CalendrierActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Menu.BBEnRoute.Trs.TrsActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Menu.BBEnRoute.Calendar.BBCalendarActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.testwebActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Menu.BBEnRoute.Calendar.MamanCalendarActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Menu.BBEnRoute.Prenom.PrenomsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_prenoms"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Menu.BBEnRoute.Calendar.MamCalAllActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Menu.BBEnRoute.Calendar.BebeCalendarActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Menu.BBEnRoute.Prenom.PrenomGarcActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Menu.BBEnRoute.Prenom.PrenomFilleActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Menu.BBEnRoute.Calendar.BBCalAllActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Menu.BBEnRoute.Prenom.PrenomSpecActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Menu.BBEnRoute.Calendar.SemaineActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="Activities.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having support libraries versions conflict. You are using beta version on support lib:

```groovy
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
```

and stable version of custom tabs:

```groovy
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'
```

You need to use same support libraries version to avoid such issues:

```groovy
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.0-beta1'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, but I'm a total beginner on android, can you tell me where to find those two?

Comment: @MohammedAminAIMEUR open `build.gradle` file in `app` directory. They are should be in `dependencies { ... }` block.  Also take a note: `compile '...'` is equal to `implementation '...'`.